# Hide one of the type params of a multi-param typeclass in a function signature

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Say I have a multi-param typeclass:

```
class B b => C a b | a -> b where
    getB :: a -> (T, b)
```

Then I want a function:

```
f :: C a b => a -> c
f = g . getB
```

Which uses another function `g :: B b => (T, b) -> c` and `getB`, so an instance `C a b` is needed.

(Disclaimer: the real problem is much more complicated, the above-mentioned is only a simplified version.)

The problem is, given the functional dependency `C a b | a -> b`, we know that `b` can be completely decided by `a`, so theoretically I should be possible not to mention `b` in the type of `f` (since it is not used elsewhere but in instance `C a b`), but I didn't find any way to achieve this.

Also note that due to the existence of constraint `B b` in class `C`, I think I cannot use a TypeFamilies extension instead, for the syntax of that leaves nowhere for the type constraint `B b` to live.

So is there any way that I can hide the implementation details (the irrelevant type parameter `b`) from the user of this function `f`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `TypeFamilies`, you could rewrite `C` into a single-parameter class as follows:

```
class B (BOf a) => C a where
  type BOf a :: *
  getB :: a -> (T, BOf a)
```

Which gives you the better looking constraint for `f`:

```
f :: C a => a -> c
```

There is (sadly) no way to omit parameters of a multi-parameter class to obtain a similar result.

Comment: That's the trouble with saying there's no way to do a thing... somebody might come along with something stupider than you're even willing to think of that does it.

Answer (score 4):

If you turn on `RankNTypes` you can make a type alias that lets you elide `b` like this:

```
type C' a t = forall b. C a b => t
f :: C' a (a -> c)
f = g . getB
```

You can even include further contexts, if necessary, inside the second argument:

```
f' :: C' a ((Num a, Ord c) => a -> c)
f' = g . getB
```

This is pretty non-standard, though. You'll want to leave an explanatory comment... and the effort of writing it might be bigger, in the end, than the effort of just including a `b` at each use of `C`.

Comment: Very glad to know this solution, but in this case I'll stick with the TypeFamilies method which gives me an ordinary function signature (I have to say this method leaves the user a really confusing grammar of the signature. If there would be a comment, I prefer to explain an extra `b` rather than an unfamiliar grammar). That said, maybe this answer solved my posted question better. I'd say this method is really surprising, when you use a `forall b` where actually only one `b` would fit.

Comment: @Krantz: It may be more clear with explicit quantifiers: `forall a. C' a (a -> X)` expands to `forall a. (forall b. C a b => a -> X)` which is exactly equivalent to omitting the quantifiers `C a b => a -> X`. Even if you don’t use it for this—the notation is a little awkward, not looking like a constraint anymore—the technique of writing type synonyms whose expansions include top-level `forall`s is handy for tidying up complex types.

Comment: @JonPurdy Yes, thanks for your explanation. They are certainly equivalent. I should have realized that there are implicit `forall`s in function signatures.